# FirebaseUI RecyclerView does not update when reference is changed and goes blank

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

So I am using a FirebaseUI FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to populate my recycler view.

My situation is I want the user to be able to select a date and view the data that is in the firebase database on that date.

To implement this I, for now have have an edit text which opens a Date Picker Dialog and sets the text in the edit text to the selected date in ddMMyyyy format.

After that when user clicks on a button the recycler view should show the data on that specific date.

The problem is, when the button is clicked, I can verify that the adapter is indeed getting the new data from the database but the recycler view goes completely empty until the keyboard is opened.

Is this even a good way of doing this? Or should I go for another approach? Any help will be appreciated.

This is my first Question here So sorry for any mistakes.

**LecturesOnDate.java**

```
public class LecturesOnDate extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText dateSelector;
    Button setDate;
    RecyclerView rcViewOnDate;
    Calendar calendar;
    Date date;
    FirebaseUIAdapterAdmin rcAdapter;

    DatabaseReference dateReference, weekReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecture_on_date);

        rcViewOnDate = findViewById(R.id.RCViewOnDate);
        dateSelector = findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
        setDate = findViewById(R.id.setButton);

        rcViewOnDate.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rcViewOnDate.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = calendar.getTime();

        String today = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy", Locale.US);
                dateSelector.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
            }
        };

        dateSelector.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatePickerDialog(AddLectureOnDate.this, date, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });


        setDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String dateOn = dateSelector.getText().toString();
          
                dateReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Lecture/5A3/edited/" + dateOn);

                
                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Lecture> options =
                        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Lecture>()
                                .setQuery(dateReference, Lecture.class)
                                .setLifecycleOwner(Lecture.this)
                                .build();

                rcAdapter = new FirebaseUIAdapterAdmin(options);
                rcViewOnDate.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

                rcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

[Here is a GIF of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LakpK.gif)

After I select a date and click on the set date button, the recycler view just goes blank until I open the keyboard by clicking on another edit text (not in the video)

**This is My Database (Edited for clarifications and making it short)**

[Here is a screenshot of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erGuf.png)

```
{
  "Lecture": {
    "5A3": {
      "edited": {
        "12102022": [     //This should represent the dateOn used in reference
          {
            "classCode": "UCSE571 LAB",
            "dateOn": "12102022",  //This is just for testing
            "endTime": "12:30",
            "startTime": "9:30",
            "teacherName": "BKC"
          }
        ],
        "18102022": [
          {
            "classCode": "UCSE503",
            "dateOn": "18102022",  //This is just for testing
            "endTime": "9:30",
            "startTime": "8:30",
            "teacherName": "RNM"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Even if the reference is present in the database, the data still doesn't load into the recycler view until keyboard is opened and then closed.

**Here is the Model Class**

```
package xyz.coolidance.xpscheduler.helpers;

public class Lecture {
    String classCode, teacherName, startTime, endTime, dateOn;

    Lecture(){

    }

    public Lecture(String classCode, String teacherName, String startTime, String endTime, String dateOn) {

        this.classCode = classCode;
        this.teacherName = teacherName;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.dateOn = dateOn;

    }

    public String getClassCode() {
        return classCode;
    }

    public String getTeacherName() {
        return teacherName;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public String getDateOn() {
        return dateOn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Besides that, what is the exact value of `dateOn` inside your reference?

Comment: @AlexMamo , I have added the database to the question and also marked where the reference is pointing to. Also thank you for helping me out and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: As far as I can see, `12102022` is an array that contains a single object, right? So how would you like to display multiple item since there is only one present?

Comment: There are multiple objects inside 12102022, the data from those objects get used in the recycler view. I just posted how the data is structured.

My problem is like this: Lets suppose I call the reference on 12102022, the data gets populated in the Recycler View, but after I set 18102022 as the reference by entering it into the edit Text and clicking on the set date button, the recycler view is empty. From the logs I can see that the reference is indeed changing but the recycler View does not update with the data from that.

Comment: Under `edited`, there are two, arrays, right?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my post as well to show the data in my database

Comment: Yes, `12102022` is an array that contains multiple objects. Please edit your question and add the content of your `Lecture` class.

Comment: I have added the Lecture Class

Comment: So if you try to log the value of `String dateOn = dateSelector.getText().toString();` are you getting `12102022`?

Comment: Yes, I am specifically making that specific date call for now but in future I will setup a logic to check if the reference exists in the database, if it's not present it will create it with some random data and then set the reference to show the data from there.

Comment: Inside your adapter class. Are you getting any data?

Comment: That I am not too sure how to look for. Maybe thats the problem. Anyway I solved my problem by replacing the recycler view with a fragment and putting the recycler view in the fragment, whenever a new reference is made, the fragment gets replaced by a new fragment. I will post my solution as an answer in a few hours. But this just feels like a temporary solution.

Comment: Try to add a log statement and see if you get the desired results, or step through the debugger and see where you get the issue.

Comment: Will do now for sure

Answer (score 1):

This is a Temporary fix that I applied to solve the problem.

I removed the `Recycler View` From The layout and replaced it with a `Frame layout` instead.

When the User sets a date, The fragment is created and showed to the user with the data.

Here are the Relevant Files

**AddLectureOnDate**

```
public class AddLectureOnDate extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText dateSelector;
    Calendar calendar;
    Date date;
    String dateOn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecture_on_date);

        dateSelector = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = calendar.getTime();

        String today = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
        String mDay = today.substring(0, 2);
        String mMonth = today.substring(2, 4);
        String mYear = today.substring(4, 8);

        dateSelector.setText(String.join("/", mDay, mMonth, mYear));
        openFragment(today);
        dateOn = today;

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy", Locale.US);
                dateOn = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

                String mDay = dateOn.substring(0, 2);
                String mMonth = dateOn.substring(2, 4);
                String mYear = dateOn.substring(4, 8);

                dateSelector.setText(String.join("/", mDay, mMonth, mYear));
                openFragment(dateOn);

            }
        };

        dateSelector.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddLectureOnDate.this, dateDialog, calendar.get(calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });    
    }

    private void openFragment(String string) {
        LectureOnDate fragment = new LectureOnDate();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("date", string);

        fragment.setArguments(data);
        transaction.replace(R.id.recyclerFragmentContainer, fragment).commit();

    }

    private void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) AddLectureOnDate.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Here is the **layout file** for **AddLectureOnDate   (activity_lecture_on_date.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLectures"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:paddingEnd="30dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="LECTURES"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="30sp">

    </TextView>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/dateSelect"
        style="@style/InputText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLectures"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:hint="Select Date"
        app:counterMaxLength="20"
        app:helperText="Required"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/Rounded">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/pickDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:focusable="false">

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dateSelect"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/line" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/recyclerFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp">

    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Fragment **(LectureOnDate.java)**

```
public class LectureOnDate extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference databaseDay, databaseWeek;
    FirebaseUIAdapterAdmin adapterAdmin;
    Calendar calendar;
    Date today;
    String recievedDate;
    TextView header;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lecture_on_date, container, false);
        Context context = view.getContext();

        header = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewOnDate);
        Bundle data = getArguments();
        if (data != null) {
            recievedDate = data.getString("date");
        }

        Log.d("Fragment", "onCreateView: LectureOnDate" + recievedDate);


        //Changing the recievedDate String to a date so that we can determine the weekday
        DateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyy");
        today = null;
        try {
            today = sourceFormat.parse(recievedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String date = recievedDate;
        String weekday_name = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(today);

        String day = recievedDate.substring(0, 2);
        String month = recievedDate.substring(2, 4);
        String year = recievedDate.substring(4, 8);

        header.setText(new StringBuilder().append(String.join("/", day, month, year)).append(",  ").append(weekday_name).toString());

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.RCViewOnDate);

        databaseDay = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Lecture/5A3/edited/" + date);
        databaseWeek = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Lecture/5A3/general/" + weekday_name);


        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Lecture> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Lecture>()
                        .setQuery(databaseDay, Lecture.class)
                        .setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner())
                        .build();

        adapterAdmin = new FirebaseUIAdapterAdmin(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterAdmin);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (adapterAdmin != null) {
            adapterAdmin.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("Fragment", "onDestroy: " + recievedDate);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And Here is the **Fragment Layout(fragment_lecture_on_date.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.Today">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOnDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="35dp"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewOnDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/today_top"
                android:textColor="@color/text"
                android:textSize="35sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RCViewOnDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayoutOnDate"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

This is a small portion of the database I am uisng:-
[Database Portion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkJy1.png)

This is the desired output for my final app :-
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Mwx.gif)